# Remove first letter of several filenames

Tags: cmd

I have a folder, and within that folder there are several csv files. Some file names start with `X`, e.g. `Xtest.csv`, `XHire.csv`, some of them not. How to remove the `X` using cmd?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file in the directory with the `X*.csv` files with the following lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in (X*.csv) do (
    set "OldFileName=%%I"
    set "NewFileName=!OldFileName:~1!"
    if not exist "!NewFileName!" ren "%%I" "!NewFileName!"
)
endlocal
```

Then run this batch file with a double click.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`